# Changing the color of Pie Charts in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, pie-chart

I want to change the  default color of Pie Charts in Angular 4. My code is so long but this the structure that i have followed but is not working.

.ts file:

```js
// .ts file

export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
    pieChartLabels: string[];
    pieChartData: number[];
    pieChartType: string = 'pie';
    pieChartLegend: boolean = false;
    pieChartColors: any[];
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.pieChartLabels = ['label 1','label 2', 'label 3', 'label 4', ...];
    this.pieChartData = [data 1, data 2, data 3, .... ];
    this.pieChartColors =
        [
            {backgroundColor:"#F42A0A",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)" },
            {backgroundColor:"#95382A",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bbzd",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bbad",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bb0d",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bb1d",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bb6d",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bb7d",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bb8d",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"},
            {backgroundColor:"#97bb9d",borderColor: "rgba(148,159,177,1)"}
        ];
    
    
// .html file


<canvas style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" baseChart [data]="pieChartData"
                        [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                        [legend]="pieChartLegend" [colors]="pieChartColors">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved by importing  "ng2-charts" from ChartsModule.

Answer (score 1):

Colors should be provided like `Array<Any>`
So you should change

```
this.pieChartColors = ["#ff9900","#ff9900","#97bbcd","#97bbcd"];
```

to something like this:

```
this.pieChartColors = [
{backgroundColor:"#ff9900", ...},
{backgroundColor:"#ff9900", ...},
{backgroundColor:"#97bbcd", ...},
{backgroundColor:"#97bbcd", ...}];
```

Example of the color structure from [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/):

```
Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
```

Comment: Thanks @MikkaRin. But now it takes all the colors from the first element of the array. If i give Red color for the first background color, all other take the same red color.

Comment: @myadsmail Check color #97bbzd - it's not a color definition. It should include only 0123456789ABCDEF symbols

Comment: i am also getting same first color for all. @MikkaRin